# How to get json string and header element using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I've been trying to get json and some header elements using this code:
And I was able to print the details that I need but it seems that I can't actually "get" them.

```
$url = 'http://192.168.254.211:8080/sampleOnCurl/auth/login';
$initCurl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($initCurl, 
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        // CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        // CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $loginData,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json', 
            'jrr: 7ffed684cbe1fc085b7b47dc4e508e99a5effee9', 
            'slave: 01bdfcc20777907712e97f7bd2faeb978584f317',
            'spoil: ' .$timeStamp
        )
    )
);
$result = curl_exec($initCurl);
print_r($result); 
//prints jrr, slave, spoil
$result = json_decode($result);
// $header = curl_getinfo($initCurl);
curl_close($initCurl);
```

and this is what I get

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
jrr: 2e278657295bdfae2bc49b0bc6ad38363e9b149b
slave: d77985811796708b89471b4d29a904b224d41dde
spoil: 20130916222842701
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 16 Sep 2013 14:28:42 GMT

{"true":null}
```

I want to get `{"true":null}` and convert it to array to check if index is `true`
and get `jrr`, `slave` and `spoil` values .. without using the get method ..

The string that is printed doesn't seem to be in json as well. My guess is that the problem is in my curl options. What could I be missing out?

Here's what I need to do:
get the json `{"true":null}`
get the Response Header: jrr, slave, spoil
avoid using Get method

thanks

Comment: You can use `HEAD` to get headers (server will interpret it like `GET` but will not send content in response). But to get JSON you have to use `GET` or `POST`.

Comment: I can't use it if it is `GET` because the server will return me an error only `POST` is allowed. On that note specifically what `HEAD` ? 
`But to get JSON you have to use GET or POST` could please elaborate ? as you can see the reponse I get doesn't seem to be in JSON format.. and I can't access them using `$result['jrr']`

Comment: `{"true":null}` is valid JSON, what is problem with that? You can also use `json_decode($result, true)` to force array format. `HEAD` is next request method (like `POST` or `GET`), it gets only headers, but you said that only `POST` is allowed so you can forget about it in that case.

Comment: it seems that when I add `$result = json_decode($result)` before `print_r` the page doesn't print anything and I think that `{"true":null}` is part of `$result` if that makes any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
list($headers, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);

function parseSimpleHeaders($headers) {
    $lines = explode("\r\n", $headers);
    $parsed = array();
    foreach($lines as $line) {
        $colon = strpos($line, ':');
        if($colon !== false) {
            $name = trim(substr($line, 0, $colon));
            $value = trim(substr($line, $colon + 1));
            $parsed[$name] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $parsed;
}

$headers = parseSimpleHeaders($headers);
$json = json_decode($body);

echo $headers['jrr'], "\n"; // 2e278657295bdfae2bc49b0bc6ad38363e9b149b
echo $headers['slave'], "\n"; // d77985811796708b89471b4d29a904b224d41dde
echo $headers['spoil'], "\n"; // 20130916222842701
var_dump($json); // object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["true"] => NULL }
```

N.B. There's a [`http_parse_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php) function in `pecl_http` but I've included my own simplified version `parseSimpleHeaders()` in case it's not installed.

Comment: thanks a lot .. I was actually thinking that there's no need to create a function to parse the header and body like `Request::header`, but I guess it doesn't work when a server is included also since the header being requested is a declaration not a default one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting response content and header in variable `$result` so you can't parse it directly.

To get it working explode `$result` using two new lines.

```
$result = explode("\n\n", $result);
```

and now you can access headers string by `$result[0]` and response content by `$result[1]` (and parse it using `json_decode($result[1], true)`.

Comment: I just tried using `$result = explode('\n\n', $result);` `$result1 = json_decode($result[1],true);` `print_r($result1);` but it gives me an error of undefined offset

Comment: @shin-shan You have to use `"` not `'`. Only in first case PHP will interpret `\n` as new line. You should know that, it's basic knowledge.

Comment: sorry about that my mistake.. but the result is just the same `Undefined offset`

Comment: Check with `var_dump` what is in `$result` before and after explode.

Comment: before explode $result is string and this is after explode `array(1) { [0]=> ... {"true":null}}`